# How to optimize and improve performance for the following code? It fetches a large num of records , hence slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

How to optimize and improve performance for the following Sql Stored procedure? It fetches a large number of records , hence results in slow performance.

The column is also non clustered indexer.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
```

---

### -- Select all  records from tblA based on T

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[Usp_SP1]  
    @T nvarchar(50)  
    AS  

    IF @T = 'ABC'  
    BEGIN  
 SELECT   
  xyz as [XYZK],  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(T)),'') AS T,  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(V)),'')  AS V,  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(Des)),'') AS Des,  
  COALESCE(Seq, 0) AS Seq,  
  COALESCE(Ac,0) AS Ac,  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(U)),'') AS U,  
  COALESCE(Ac,0) AS Ac,
    COALESCE(L,0) AS _L,
        COALESCE(M,0) AS _M,
        COALESCE(E,0) AS _E,
        COALESCE(S,0) AS _S


 FROM tblA WITH (NOLOCK)  
 WHERE  T = @T  ORDER BY V, Seq  
END   
ELSE  
BEGIN  
 SELECT   
  xyz as [XYZK],  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(T)),'') AS T,  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(V)),'')  AS V,  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(Des)),'') AS Des,  
  COALESCE(Seq, 0) AS Seq,  
  COALESCE(Ac,0) AS Ac,  
  COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(U)),'') AS U,  
  COALESCE(Ac,0) AS Ac,
    COALESCE(L,0) AS _L,
        COALESCE(M,0) AS _M,
        COALESCE(E,0) AS _E,
        COALESCE(S,0) AS _S


 FROM tblA WITH (NOLOCK)   
 WHERE  T = @T  ORDER BY Seq 
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

The query should take min time to execute and should be optimized.

Comment: Do you have an index on tblA fields T ? And also... how many records aproximately are in the table and in the expected results?

Comment: Can you apply the `TRIM` on the data stored in the table?

Comment: It looks like the only difference between those two queries is in the `ORDER BY`. If that's so, you could just have one query and write `ORDER BY CASE WHEN @t = 'ABC' THEN V END,Seq`

Comment: @AngelM. Yes I do have a non clustered index on tblA field 'T'. There are over 8k records and expected results have approx 7k records.

Comment: @EzLo I am afraid , we cannot.

Comment: Maybe you can create calculated fields: < ALTER TABLE dbo.tblA ADD T_Trimmed AS (COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(T)),'') ); >. The same for all TRIMMED columns and then select the new columns

Comment: If you return almost all the records and your index is not covering(with all the fields from your SELECT as included), it's not used at all. But I'm surprised how can it perform slowly on such a small volume of data. What is the size of your table(in Mb)?

Comment: @sepupic its 5.224 mb for me. But there is another aspect, the data varies from role to role. SO it is possible that the client is getting considerable large amount of data from the same procedure. So, more focus has to be in SP optimization and performance enhancement

Comment: Please paste the actual execution plan and update your question with the link to it. I suspect that, as you said, there can be very small amount of data also. This means that if your plan was compiled for such a parameter that sp returns very few rows, it could use the index. But this is not suitable when you return almost all the table. I'm afraid your plan has lookups into base table and this is terrible for large volumes of data.If it's so, OPTION(RECOMPILE) may help

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Will this enhance performance as well? This is clearly optimizing the code.(I am working on it though)

Comment: Is the problem with the actual query running in the database or the end to end time the query is taking to return i.e. including network traffic?  You could use SQL Profiler to find out if you don't know.   If most of the time is spent returning results over the network then one option would be to change to a paging approach if that were possible.

Comment: Rewriting 2 queries as one of course will not give you any performance gain. But what about the execution plan? Did you try to use recompile option?