# Incorrect syntax for Order by clause with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, case

How to write order by clause with multiple columns in a case statement?

```
 ORDER BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Val,Seq
 ELSE Seq END
```

Also tried

```
 ORDER BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Convert(int,Val) 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Convert(nvarchar,Seq)
 ELSE Seq END

 ORDER BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Val,Seq
 ELSE Seq END
```

Also the below given code throws error:

> "This statement is giving error: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'EX-02-60' to data type int" when the Stored Procedure is executed."

Comment: That attempt is backwards. Put the case _expression_ inside the ORDER BY.

Comment: I already told you exactly what to write in a comment on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54106616/15498) when I suggested this change.

Comment: OP I update my answer to be clear and for more details and include a live demo too.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes you did. But I was facing issues with the syntax and there was another error occurring. Hence I added this post as a separate chain. Though that question still remains open as , the code has been optimized but the performance still remains the same and I have mentioned the same in that question as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's Create a table which has your columns

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Val VARCHAR(45),
  Seq INT,
  Sequence INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('A', 1, 2),
('C', 2, 1),
('B', 3, 3);
```

Now, let's look to your code and then brings the conditions:

Here is your code:

```
 ORDER BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Val,Seq
 ELSE Sequence END
```

- If `@T = 'ABC` then order by `Val` and `Seq` **AND DO NOT** order by `Sequence`.
- If `@T <> 'ABC'` then order **Only** with `Sequence`.

If you run this query:

```
--You was trying--

DECLARE @T VARCHAR(3) = 'ABC'; --wil works only when @T <> ABC

SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @T='ABC' THEN Seq END, --Take INT
         CASE WHEN @T='ABC' THEN Val --Take Varchar
              ELSE Sequence -- Take INT
         END;
```

It will throw the following error if `@T = 'ABC'`

> Msg 245 Level 16 State 1 Line 5
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.

same as you get

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'EX-02-60' to data type int.

Now, here is what you want according to the conditions you provide:

```
--Fixes--

DECLARE @T VARCHAR(3) = '1'; --Try to change it to ABC too

SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @T='ABC' THEN Val END, --Take varchar
         CASE WHEN @T='ABC' THEN Seq -- Take INT
              ELSE Sequence -- Take INT
         END;
/*
 IF @T = ABC
 ORDER BY Val, Seq; NOT Sequence
 
 IF @T <> ABC
 ORDER BY ONLY Sequence
*/
```

And here is a **[Live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=28fa52d93352b1e9733264f7a9268c13)**

Comment: The earlier code worked fine for me. I haven't tested the latest one that you provided yet.

Comment: @SRawat The earlier code works fine for you because the CAST(), but it doesn't take `Sequence` column in count.

Comment: How come I do not have a way to contact you except for SO

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you're after is:

```
ORDER BY CASE @T WHEN 'ABC' THEN Val END,
         CASE @T WHEN 'ABC' THEN Seq END,
         [Sequence];
```

---

To elaborate on why you're attempts didn't work. Firstly:

```
WHERE  Type = @T  ORDER BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Val,Seq
 ELSE Sequence END
```

A `CASE` is an expression that returns a **scalar** value. Here your `WHEN` tried to return 2 values. That's not allowed.

```
 ORDER BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Convert(int,Val) 
 WHEN @T='ABC' Then Convert(nvarchar,Seq)
 ELSE Seq END
```

As `CASE` is returns a scalar value it can only return one datatype. The `CASE` expression uses datatype precendence, and `int` has a higher precendence than `nvarchar` so `Seq` would be implicitly converted to an `int`; and I'd hazard a guess that that failed.

Comment: This statement is giving error:  "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'EX-02-60' to data type int"  when the Stored Procedure is executed.

Comment: That won't be the `ORDER BY` returning that error @ShradhaR. There's no implicit conversions in my solution. That error is from elsewhere in your SQL that you haven't provided us.

Comment: An explicit conversion Convert(nvarchar,Seq) won;t work in this scenario? if not, then could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there @ShradhaR. I don't have an explicit or implicit conversion in my solution. The error you are getting (with the `ORDER BY` I have provided) isn't because of the `ORDER BY` clause. It's somewhere else.

Comment: If you post your **full** SQL, along with DDL in your question, then we can help you trouble shoot that as well. Or perhaps ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @sami `CASE @T WHEN 'ABC' THEN Val END,` will return the datatype of `Val`. If `Val` is a `varchar`, then that's the datatype it'll return. The `NULL` would be implicitly cast to a `varchar`; a `NULL` doesn't have the datatype `int` by default. Otherwise an expression like `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'abc' END` would fail.

Comment: @Sami . . . This is the right solution and it provides a good explanation of why as well.

Comment: And I have replicated that logic, @Sami by a different method. If `@T` has a value of `ABC`' then data will be sorted (in ascending order) by `Val`, then `Seq`, and then finally `Sequence`. If `@T` has any other value (including `NULL`), then the data will be sorted by the value `NULL` (so no order), followed by then value `NULL` (again, no order), and then `Sequence`; effectively meaning the data will be sorted in by `Sequence`. Just because the OP used `CASE...ELSE` logic doesn't mean the solution needs to.

Comment: @Sami Where are you seeing any casting in my solution? Neither `CASE @T WHEN 'ABC' THEN Val END,` or `CASE @T WHEN 'ABC' THEN Seq END,` have any implicit (or explicit) casting. Like I said before `NULL` does not have a default data type and, in this case, will be `CAST` to the data type of `Val` and `Seq` respectively in each of these `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @Sami I don't have an `ELSE` in my logic... You appear to have misread my SQL. I've edited your DB fiddle to show what my logic is. I've also editted the sample data to show what happens when `@T` doesn't have the value `'abc'`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f29e74ba4fab8a58eae0287b6dc1b14c)

Comment: @Larnu That is false cause now you will always order by NN, (sequence in OP Q)

Comment: Err... @Sami did you run the fiddle. Note that the 2 datasets have 2 different orders... I've tried, but clearly this conversion is over/lost.

Answer (score 0):

The Data type of the Value in the `ORDER BY` should always be same. Here you will get the conversion error because in the first Case the Data Type is INT and in the second one, it is Varchar. SO For More Secure way, you may use the following approach

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN_Val = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Val),
        RN_Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Seq),
        *
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        ORDER BY 
        (
            CASE @T
                WHEN 'ABC' THEN RN_Val
                WHEN 'XYZ' THEN RN_Seq
            END
        )
```